# How do you join the points in an ECharts scatter charts?

Tags: javascript, echarts

line vs scatter
I would like to join the points with a line in the scatter charts, like Scatter Line Chart in Chart js adding showLine: true.

```
option = {
  xAxis: {},
  yAxis: {},
  series: [
    {
      symbolSize: 20,
      data: [
        [10.0, 8.04],
        [8.07, 6.95],
        [7.07, 6.95],
        [13.0, 7.58]
        ],
      type: 'scatter'
    },
      {
      symbolSize: 1,
      color: 'red',
      data: [
        [3.0, 8],
        [3.0, 4],
        ],
      type: 'line',
      lineStyle: {
                "width": "2"
      },
    }
   
   ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of drawing lineS on the scatter chart, you can draw scatter on the line chart, they will have exactly same effect:

[image]

Here's the config for it:

```
option = {
  xAxis: {},
  yAxis: {},
  series: [
    {
      symbolSize: 20,
      data: [
        [7.07, 6.95],
        [8.07, 6.95],
        [10.0, 8.04],
        [13.0, 7.58]
      ],
      symbol: 'circle',
      type: 'line'
    }
   ]
};
```

Comment: Thank you, now I have to check and make some changes.